# PHP : rename() How do I find the error cause?

Tags: php

I would like to print out the cause of the error.

error_get_last() doesn't seem to return anything. rename() returns TRUE|FALSE rather than an exception.

```
if (!rename($file->filepath, $full_path)) {
  $error = error_get_last();
  watchdog('name', "Failed to move the uploaded file from %source to   %dest", array('%source' => $file->filepath, '%dest' => $full_path));
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to solve a bug or would you like this to be a functionality of your final program? If it's a bug rename emits E_WARNING you can read if you set error_reporting to show E_NOTICE. If this is for production you should add some file checks like the answer just posted suggested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was 'another error handler' was capturing the errors as per the comment in the php manual for http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php. In this case it was the drupal error handler and the error was being captured into the error log there.

Comment: Should have stated you were using a framework in you're question. Frameworks do a lot of stuff for you and often changes the advice you will receive.

Answer (score 7):

First, it's a better practice to add some safety checks before:

```
if (file_exists($old_name) && 
    ((!file_exists($new_name)) || is_writable($new_name))) {
    rename($old_name, $new_name);
}
```

Second, you can turn on error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: This wasn't working because there was 'another error handler. I was running through with the debugger and expecting errors, but drupal was capturing them. Both rename() and copy() do report messages. Note to error_get_last() was what got me to twig http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php. I was a bit paranoid check, or create dir file_check_directory($path, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to do this is to do a `copy()` to copy to the new name required (which you can verify) with messages... and then use unlink() to delete the original.

But yes, `rename()` does exactly as you say and generates no errors when it doesn't work :)

Comment: both copy() and rename() did the same thing when I worked out the error handler thing

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to move a uploaded file, use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) instead.

Comment: Insightful and I like the idea of tools for purpose. Digressing from my Q - I didn't say this was drupal. Using http://drupal.org/project/upload_element which then calls drupal file_save_upload(). Sanitises files and puts it in tmp dir. The upload can be ajax based or on submission. So I don't trust $_POST and the file is on disk. That is why I was just doing rename()

Comment: move_uploaded_file() worked for me and I don't know why rename() doesn't work. But thanks.