# PHP rename() 'etc/testfile1.txt' to '/testfile2.txt' seem to delete the file

Tags: php

I've unfortunately deleted a slew of files because my script to move them didn't end up including the actual path I intended to move them to, but instead 'moved' the files to the filename with a slash in front.

This is how to reproduce. Execute this line:

```
$myfile = fopen("testfile1.txt", "w");
```

Then execute this line:

```
rename('testfile1.txt', '/testfile2.txt');
```

I know how to do this correctly, and I know it would not be a good idea to rename a file this way but I'm asking this question because I've inadvertently done this by now and it has resulted in the apparent deletion of several important files I was trying to move.

Does anyone know why this is behaving this way? And more importantly, is there any way I can recover my missing files? I've tried using Recuva and file searching the whole drive to no avail

This is on Windows 10 Pro using XAMPP, using an administrator account.

Thanks.

Comment: Your user probably doesn't have access to the root of your server. Remove the `/` from the destination location.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks for your response. I've updated the question to better communicate that I'm on Windows 10 using XAMPP on an administrator account, and that I understand how to properly use rename(). My main issue is how to get these files back.

Comment: I'd guess the files are gone. It had permission to take it from the directory you were in but lacked permissions to write the new file. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360511/php-rename-how-do-i-find-the-error-cause

Comment: Thankfully I managed to just rename them back even though they seemed gone and even though PHP said they didn't exist. Please see my answer for more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to try rename('/my-missing-file.txt', 'my-missing-file.txt') to recover one of the missing files, but despite the error it gave ("file cannot be found"), I happened to noticed that it worked anyway, but it put the file in the directory of the php script. So I repeated this process and managed to get my files back!

So at least it fails both ways.
Thanks folks.

Comment: I guess this is a bug in php then

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/` from `'/testfile2.txt'` so it's named `'testfile2.txt'` what you are doing is simply moving it to root and if you don't have access to root you are assuming they are being deleted.

if you want to rename within etc. then you would have to name it `'etc/filename2.txt'`

In linux the name of the file is basically the whole name so when you slap a `/` in front of it you are just removing any other folder it was in and moving it to the root with that file name.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm on windows 10 pro using XAMPP, is there still a way to access 'root' and find my missing files? I attempted to do rename('/my-missing-file.txt', 'my-missing-file.txt') to recover the files but PHP said the file cannot be found.

Comment: So, when I do this in windows it's telling me access is denied. You're not getting any error like that?

Comment: Also consider xampp may be your test enviorment but if you're hosting in a server it won't be windows.

Comment: No I wasn't getting any error, but just now I"ve figured it out. It turns out that PHP fails both ways. So when I did rename('/my-missing-file.txt', 'my-missing-file.txt') to recover one of the files, despite the error it gave I happened to noticed that it worked anyway, but it put the file in the directory of the php script. So I repeated this process and managed to get my files back! I posted my answer to my question and will mark it accepted soon as I can.